# Sagemath expression does not solve

Tags: python, list, sage

I am trying to implement this equation in SageMath as a function:

```
def prob_k(p_uv_list, tw):
    probs = []
    w, k = var('w, k')
    # compute probability of generating k entanglements, k=1..w
    for tk in range(tw):
        pk = binomial(w, k)*(p_uv_list[tk]**k)*(1-p_uv_list[tk])**(w-k).subs({x:tw,k:tk})
        probs += [pk]
    return probs
```

The input is a list of probabilities and an integer. I want the output to be a list of probabilities computed given the formula for pk. What I get is:

```
[0.500000000000000^k*0.500000000000000^w*binomial(w, k),
 0.500000000000000^k*0.500000000000000^(w - 1)*binomial(w, k),
 0.500000000000000^k*0.500000000000000^(w - 2)*binomial(w, k)]
```

Why does it not substitute w and k for tw and tk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using subs, you can simply substitute the values of tw and tk directly in the expression using parentheses and the replace method

You can try this code :

```
def prob_k(p_uv_list, tw):
    probs = []
    w, k = var('w k')
    # compute probability of generating k entanglements, k=1..w
    for tk in range(tw):
        pk = binomial(w, k)*(p_uv_list[tk]**k)*(1-p_uv_list[tk])**(w-k)
        pk = pk.replace(w, tw).replace(k, tk)
        probs += [pk]
    return probs
```